# Maximum electric field of a circular ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, differentiation

How do you differentiate the equation for electric field of uniform ring 
$$ E_x = \frac{kxQ}{(x^2+r^2)^{3/2}} $$to get the maximum at a point? My book says $x = r/\sqrt2$. I tried differentiating using the quotient rule, the chain rule, etc., but I am not getting this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ignore the coefficients, your function will be
$$f(x) = \frac x{\left(x^2 + r^2\right)^{3/2}}.$$

Differentiating w.r.t $x$ gives you
$$\begin{align}
\text{simple product rule}\ f(x) &= u(x)\times v(x);\quad u(x) = x;\quad v(x) = \frac1{(x^2 + r^2)^{3/2}}\\
f'(x) &= u'(x)\times v(x) + u(x)\times v'(x)\\
f'(x) &= \frac1{(x^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{\left(-\frac32\right)2x^2}{(x^2 + r^2)^{5/2}}
\end{align}$$

To maximize/minimize you substitute $f'(x) = 0$,
$$\frac1{(x^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{3x^2}{(x^2 + r^2)^{5/2}}$$
which can be simplified to
$$3x^2 = x^2 + r^2$$
giving you the solution
$$x = \pm\frac r{\sqrt2}.$$